# Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource - enable CORS on xampp

Tags: php, apache, cors

I am trying to receive json data using XmlHttpRequest from another file on same server i.e. localhost. But I am getting **Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://localhost/folder/data.php. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).**

I tried using different solutions searching from the SO but nothing working. The solutions I tried include adding   `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` to apache  in the httpd.con file. It didn't work.

Then to add solution in php code, I added php header

```
<?php
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
 header('Content-Type: application/json');

 header('Content-Type: application/json');
?>
```

to the data.php file that's sending json data from server. But same result.

I also added name of specific file requesting json like `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://localhost.request.php`"); But it didn't succeeded.

Here is my data.php file to send json data.

**Data.php**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost/folder/request.php');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS');

header('Content-Type: application/json');
?>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="300">
    <title>Weather Data</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

</head>
<body> 


    <?php

    require("Connection2.php");

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("Select humidity, temperature FROM weatherdata");
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $WData = array();
    foreach($stmt->fetchAll() as $k=>$v) {       
    $WData[] = $v;
    }
    echo json_encode($WData);
    ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

**httpd.conf**

```
  <Directory />
        AllowOverride none
        Require all denied
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

  </Directory>


  <Files ".ht*">
        Require all denied
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </Files>
```

**JS code**

```
 <script>

    function loadChart() { //fetches json data & calls dspChart() to render graph 
        var wData, hum, tem;
        var requestURL = 'https://localhost/folder/data.php'; //URL of the JSON data
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest({
        mozSystem: true
        }); // create http request
        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
        wData = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        hum = wData.humidity;
        tem = wData.temperature;
        humArray.shift();
        humArray.push(hum);
        temArray.shift();
        temArray.push(tem);
        dspChrt(humArray, temArray);
        }
    }
        request.open('GET', requestURL);
        request.send(); **//statement causing CORS error;**
    }
        var myVar = setInterval(loadChart, 60000);
    </script>
```

Comment: Where's the JavaScript that is sending the request? Which request headers is it sending? FYI, you're going to run into JSON parsing troubles later with that echo-ing `json_encode()` in a loop

Comment: Have you checked if the header is being set as you expect? Make a simple HTTP request to the URL. Look at the HTTP response headers in the developer tools of your browser.

Comment: Do you really need to set CORS globally for every URL on the server? Wouldn't it be simpler to just do it within the PHP script which needs public cross-origin access?

Comment: Which bit of that JS is triggering the CORS error? I don't see anything there which would.

Comment: "I am sending json data from apache server on xampp to another file on same server " — Are you sure it is the same server? Normally that would mean you were working with the same origin.

Comment: @Quentin: I don't need to set CORS globally on local server. If I can do this within the php script, will be very nice. How can I find which part of js is causing this? Yes, another file in same directory is accessing it.

Comment: "If I can do this within the php script, will be very nice." — Then write PHP to output the HTTP header.

Comment: "How can I find which part of js is causing this?" — The CORS error message should tell you which line triggered it

Comment: "Yes, another file in same directory is accessing it." — This sounds like the error isn't coming from where you think it is.

Comment: @Quentin: sorry, I put wrong js file. Please see the edited one. There is no other file accessing the echo json data.php.

Comment: The Chrome shows that request.send(); statement of JS code raising error.

Comment: I added the header
<?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost/folder/index.php');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS');
    ?>
to the data sending file as you mentioned to allow it in  php but still is not working.

Answer (score -3):

"Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) is a **security relaxation** measure that needs to be implemented in some APIs in order to let web browsers access them. However, when CORS is enabled by a back-end developer some security analysis needs to be done in order to ensure you’re not relaxing your server security too much." (from https://mobilejazz.com/blog/which-security-risks-do-cors-imply/)

CORS isn't necessarily dangerous to have enabled, so long as you understand and mitigate the risks. However, there is an alternative solution that does not require having CORS enabled.

Instead of calling a different domain from Javascript, create a proxy page in PHP, which can call the other domain via curl/guzzle, and it doesn't care about CORS.

```
$('#mybutton').click(function(){
    $.get('/another/page/on/the/same/site', {vars: here}, function(e){
        console.log(e); // Whatever your scrtipt sends back
    });
});
```

Then in your PHP script:

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://the-domain-blocked-by-cors/some/endpoint");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
            "postvar1=value1&postvar2=value2&postvar3=value3");

// in real life you should use something like:
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 
//          http_build_query(array('postvar1' => 'value1')));

// receive server response ...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);
```

Then work on the data, and send your JSON response!

One last thing. Before echoing your JSON, send the correct Content-Type header:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo $json;
exit;
```

Comment: _"It's better (safer) leaving CORS disabled"_ <- a statement like that needs backing up with some citations / data

Comment: *"It's better (safer) leaving CORS disabled* stupidest thing I've heard this week. You also keep your car opened all the time I guess, it's safer this way.

Comment: Phil, updated with more info. Emix, CORS is reducing security. It's fine so long as you know what you're doing.

Comment: @delboy1978uk: thank you for the answer. I will look into doing this way too since it seems interesting doing via curl/guzzle so no CORS trouble.

Comment: Hi @XCeptable how did you get on?